# How to mock jquery ajax call while testing angular page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajaxform, httpbackend, e2e-testing

I'm writing e2e test for my angular page with **protractor**.
I use $httpBackend for mocking requests which are sent by $http
But in one old page i found jquery ajaxFrom plugin which sends call by jquery ajax.
I noticed that it couldn't be mocked by $httpBackend

What is the best solution for mocking this stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation I found quite simple way to handle jquery ajax calls from angular page (which is made by jquery ajaxForm plugin)
In our test spec i just put

```
browser.executeScript( '$.fn.ajaxForm = function(form){return{submit: function(){form.success([{result: "ok"}]);}}}' );
```

So in this way i mocked request that is being sent by jquery ajaxForm plugin.

Also in same way we can mock native JS XMLHTTPRequest object

```
            window.XMLHttpRequest = function(){
                return{
                    send: function(){return true;},
                    open: function(){return true;},
                    status: 200,
                    responseText: '{result: "ok"}',
                    getAllResponseHeaders: function(){return true;},
                    readyState: 4
                }
            }
```